# Error with rand() function: same numbers into a for loop

Tags: c

I have a problem with the rand() function. I would like to randomly generate eps values, different one from each other for i=0,...,VOL. 
However, when I print eps, it is always the same. 
Could you please tell what it is wrong in my code? Thank you.

```
    ...
    #include <time.h>
    ...

    void function(...);

    int main(){

    function();

    return 0;
    }

    void function(...){

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    ...

    for(i=0;i<VOL;i++){

            signal1[i]=0.; // No signal

            eps=rand()/(RAND_MAX+0.5);

            if(signal1[i]==(MIN+MAX)){ 

                net[i]= 0; 

                exp[i]=a+eps; 
                printf("eps: %f\n", eps);

            } 
    }
    }
```

The full part of the code (to copy the entire code is impossible as it is very long) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define VOL 15

#define MAX 10
#define MIN 0

float random_sign_high[VOL]={2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0};
float random_sign_low[VOL]={2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0};

void function();

int main(){

function();

return 0;
}

void function(){
...
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

for(i=0;i<VOL;i++){

        signal1[i]=0.; // No signal
        signal2[i]=0.; // No signal


        if(H_PR!=0){
             shuffle_signals(random_sign_high);
        }

        if(L_PR!=0){
            shuffle_signals(random_sign_low);
        }

        eps=rand()/(RAND_MAX+0.5);
        printf("eps: %f\n", eps);

        if(tot_sig==(MIN+MAX)){

            net[i]= 0;

            exp_p[i]=a+eps;

        }
```

and the shuffle function is:

```
double shuffle_signals(float array[VOL])

{
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    if(VOL>1)
    {
        int i,j,t;
        for(i=0; i<VOL;i++)
        {
            j=i+rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/(VOL-i)+1.);
            t=array[j];
            array[j]=array[i];
            array[i]=t;

            if(array[i]==1){
                signal2[i]=MIN;
                signal1[i]=MAX;
            }
            else if(array[i]==0){
                signal2[i]=MIN;
                signal1[i]=MIN;
            }
            else if (array[i]==2){
                signal1[i]=MAX;
                signal2[i]=MAX;
            }
            tot_sig= signal1[i]+signal2[i];
        }
        // printf("tot_sign: %lf\n", tot_sig);
    }
    return tot_sig;
}

}
```

The other parts are irrelevant. You can think 'a' be a constant, H_PR=0.5 and L_PR=0.1
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try removing the `(unsigned int)` from in front of the `time(NULL)`?

Comment: Thank you, Annabelle. Unfortunately, I tried to remove (unsigned int) from in front of the time(NULL), but eps is always the same. I have no idea where my error is.

Comment: Can you please include the full code, or strip out the irrelevant parts further? As it is now, I can't compile it to test. Since a lot of variables aren't defined.

Comment: Any time you compare a float using `==` then your code is wrong.

Comment: _Could you please tell what it is wrong in my code?_  It does not compile.  Get it to compile first, then step through with a debugger.  With the code in its current state, its not easy to know what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, stark. I've just changed the type of tot_sig, but eps is always the same.

Comment: What type is eps ? Judging from the printf() call it is some kind of float, but I cannot se the declaration

Comment: the function: `function()`  is: 1) being prototyped to allow any number  (including 0) parameters of any type.  Suggest the prototype be: `void function( void );`  2) the posted code is missing the end of the function body.

Comment: regarding: `j=i+rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/(VOL-i)+1.);`  the `1.` had type `double`  perhaps it would be better to define it correctly as: `1.f`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.  2) use appropriate horizontal spacing inside parens, around C operators, after semicolons, after commas.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the array `array[]` is a `float` type.  comparing the values to integer numbers, like 1, 2, is not a good idea.  Many integer values cannot be exactly represented in `float`.   Instead compare to `float` values, like 1.0f, 2.0f

Comment: the arrays: `signal1[]` and `signal2[]` are not defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [`srand()` — why call it only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once/) — but I used my vote to close as there wasn't an MCVE so I can't close it as a duplicate too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `shuffle_signals()` repeatedly from inside a loop. Each time you visit this function, you call `srand()`, which resets the random number generator based on the current time (seconds since 1970). You should only call `srand()` once in your program. Somewhere near the top of `main()` would be a good place to do it.

Comment: Thank you, @squeamish ossifrage. As you suggested, eps is different. However, I lost information about my random_sign_high and low. In fact, the number of elements with MAX and MIN is not always that one I have fixed at the beginning. How can I solve it? I have one more question: if I use rand() into more functions, can I call srand() in each of them or just in main()?

Comment: *"... the number of elements with MAX and MIN is not always that one I have fixed at the beginning."* — I have no idea what you mean by this. It doesn't matter how many functions you use `rand()` in. **Unless you want to receive the same sequence of numbers again, you should only call `srand()` once. I suggest you do this somewhere near the top of `main()`.**

Answer (score 1):

the function: `shuffle_signals()` is recursive, However, the function: `srand()` should be called only once in the whole program.  Suggest moving the call to `srand()` to early in the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
int main ()
{
    int x;
    x = rand() % 100; // here you got always the same value
    printf ("Our first number: %d\n", x);
    srand ( time(NULL) ); // from now on you'll get random values
    x = rand() % 100;
    printf ("Some random number: %d\n", x);
    x = rand() % 100;
    printf ("The first number again: %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

There's nothing affects random values in when adding `unsigned int` in `srand(unsigned int(time(NULL)))` so you can add it or leave it the result is ok.

Comment: Although keep in mind that time() returns the number of *seconds* since the epoch, so if you rerun the program quickly enough, it'll generate the same seed both times.